# Single navigation bar across website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building a web application for my employer, but I have some restrictions. It has to be in HTML, CSS, and Javascript for the front end, and I have to use a lot of different pages for this, each sharing the same navigation bar.

If the navigation is the same for each page, is it possible to write the navigation bar once and use it across the entire website? I am just annoyed when I make a change to a link or something and I have to run through and change each pages respective navigation link. Normally I'd use something like Angular to achieve this, but I am not sure how to do it with this more barebones approach. They really don't use any JS libraries either so if there's a way to do it with "raw" HTML CSS and JS I'd love to learn how this works if it exists.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a "HTML" framework? you could use Polymer which allows you to create new HTML Tags. https://www.polymer-project.org/ or you create speperate Website which contains your navigation and include this as iframe (no framework)

Comment: have a look on that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/html-css-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages to load on your page your need code.

Comment: Oldschool approach: http://html.com/frames/ (please don't use this. just posting for educational purposes)

Comment: How is it possible to do this without HTML, CSS or Javascript? How is using those a "restriction"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS Navigation Bar on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/html-css-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## JQuery

As JQuery is JS-based, you might be allowed to use it. You could then add a navigation div into each page's template:

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

and include a script on each page that executes the following JQuery-code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#navigation").load("navigation.html");
});
```

## Pure JavaScript

Alternatively, if you cannot use JQuery whatsoever, you could use plain JavaScript, which is more lightweight but not as clean.

Wherever you want to include the navigation, simply include a script:

```
<script src="nav.js"></script>
```

Which holds your navigation based on `document.write`:

```
document.write('<div>\
    ... your navigation content ...\
    </div>\
');
```

Comment: Would this work if I used bootstrap to build the navigation?

Comment: Absolutely, yes! You would be referencing the bootstrap stylesheet in your page's html file and jquery/javascript would basically just append the content you load/write to the current file - in such a way that the written content knows the included stylesheets/scripts.

Comment: So JQuery is allowed for me to use. For that example, where would you write the HTML to be referenced?

Comment: In my example, the `navigation.html` would plain simple contain the navigation, nothing else. You could then use the JQuery call I provided at the point in your document(s) where you would normally put your navigation.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would just be to write the code in a JS file, and include that code on your pages. You can hard code it or make it more intelligent, but here's a basic demo.

```js
var html = '<ul>\
              <li>\
                <a href="#">link</a>\
              </li>\
              <li>\
                <a href="#">link</a>\
              </li>\
              <li>\
                <a href="#">link</a>\
              </li>\
            </ul>';

document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<nav id="nav"></nav>
```

Comment: Would this work if I was using bootstrap? What I mean is, would bootstrap still be recognized if I wrote the HTML template in the JS class?

Comment: Yep, just use whatever classes you would in normal HTML.

Comment: this is super fugly

Answer (score 4):

You can include `html` files inside html with the w3 library.

```
<div w3-include-html="navbar.html"></div>

<script>
    w3.includeHTML();
</script>
```

Check out this w3schools [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp).