# How to create multipage website using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create o portfolio site but i dont understand how to create and then manipulate every webpage on my website with css and other things..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is **wayyy** too broad. StackOverflow expects you to showcase a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [**try something**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), then come back stating **exactly** which of the individual parts you are struggling with. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score -1):

Obsidian Age's comment is correct that your question is too broad, but I suspect that you don't even know what to ask.
Each of your pages will make reference to a site-wide css file. This will keep your style in the one place. Change it and your entire site will change. 
In this way each page you have would start with:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

If you have more than a few pages, you might want to think about using another programming language to load a html file containing your nav/menu html. So that you don't have to make the same changes to every page that you want the menu on. See:

[HTML/CSS Navigation Bar on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/html-css-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)