# What is the best way to display different HTML pages (navigation)?

Tags: html, web-applications, navigation

[I know this is a duplicate] - but there are many options

Say I have this navigation menu in the dashboard (See figure below). What would be the best way to navigate through all the different pages?

[How can I reuse a navigation bar on multiple pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages) - I found an interesting concept answered by [@Ramtin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6026516/ramtin), but there is a comment below it from [@Laryx Decidua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465139/laryx-decidua) saying that an update of `jQuery` may cause problems. Although this solution is neat, and requires no customization of separate files as all the navigation is in one file.

Do I need to create multiple `.html` files - one for each option of my navigation? Well everybody knows it's possible. The question is what is the best to use?

This [article](http://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/), suggests more than 10 options of how this can be achieved. But what is the best option. What option does industries use, Google, Microsoft etc?

I'm using:

`HTML5` `CCS3` `JS` `jQuery` `BootStrap`

`NodeJS` (listens on `port:3000`)

`IIS-10` (listens on `port:80`) with `reverse-proxy` (listens on `port:3000`)

`XAMPP` (`APACHE:80` , `MySQL:3306`)

[image: DEMO EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 1):

Switch to .php, you will be able to re-use bits (include_once ...) and templates across your whole website but without any other dependencies. The only required thing is xampp (or else) which is a local server.

You dont have to know anything about php to do this, just by using the .php extension you will be able to call different files from one file (eg: Calling a navigation from a specific page).

It's also a great gateway to the "real" way of website making... One last thing, jumping straight to Wordpress (which is a CMS) might be the best way to learn. You might want to take a look a "creating your own wordpress template from scratch" they're great series out-there on the internet.

Comment: Thanks @amarinediary. Will look into it :D