# Creating a Static/Fixed Nav Bar with Only HTML

Tags: html, menu, header, nav

hope you're doing well.

My boss recently asked me to rebuild the nav bar on our site.

He wants to move away from our current method of just having the nav code on each and every web page - so we can make edits to the nav bar periodically that will be automatically implemented across the website.

He built our website back in the early days of web dev, and as such it is basically an HTML animal that really just gets the job done (and has for years) but is not responsive or pretty.

He's adamantly against using any sort of PHP or JS, since my initial thought was a JQuery script to grab a nav.html file on each page. Bummer!

That being said, does anyone know how I can essentially create the same results? Having a singular file or block of code that can be changed and then reflected on all pages across our site , using only HTML?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Here is the code we currently have copied to all of our pages, which was created long ago:

```
    <div id="navbox">

                <!----BEGIN NAV----->
                <!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/library/mainsite_nav.lbi" -->
                <link href="css_files/nav_control_main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <ul id="nav_horiz">

                    <li class="navbar"></li>

                    <li class="navbar"><a href="#">Products</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Underwater Lasers</a>
                                <ul class="flyout">
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Underwater&nbsp;Scanners</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Subsea&nbsp;Scanners</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_nm200uw_hardware.html">Nuclear&nbsp;Underwater&nbsp;Scanner</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="scan_pt200uw_pantilt.html">Laser&nbsp;Scanner&nbsp;PanTilt&nbsp;Arm</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="pdf/D_A_data_sheet_5_2_16.pdf">Angle/Distance Scanner</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="power.htm">Nuclear Inspection</a>
                                <ul class="flyout1">
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_nm200e_hardware.html">Core Verification System</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_nm200uw_hardware.html">Nuclear&nbsp;Underwater&nbsp;Scanner</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="robot_inspector_land.html">Inspector&nbsp;In-Tank&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_rpv.html">Upper&nbsp;RPV&nbsp;Measuring&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_numac100.html">Restricted&nbsp;Area&nbsp;Access&nbsp;Control</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_robotics.htm">Robotics<a href="robot_inspector_land.html"></a>
                                    <ul class="flyout2">
                                        <li class="navdrop"><a href="robot_inspector_land.html">Inspector&nbsp;In-Tank&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                                        <li class="navdrop"><a href="robot_surveyor.html">Surveyor&nbsp;Inspection&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                                        <li class="navdrop"><a href="robot_pressdie_vision.html">Press&nbsp;Die&nbsp;Vision&nbsp;System</a></li>
                                        <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_rpv.html">Upper&nbsp;RPV&nbsp;Measuring&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                                        <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_machine_vision-1.htm">Machine Vision</a>
                                <ul class="flyout3">

                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="line_systems.htm">Line&nbsp;&&nbsp;Area&nbsp;Scanning</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_noncontact.html">Non-Contact&nbsp;Gauging</a></li>

                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_surface_defect.html">Surface&nbsp;Defects</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_pattern_match.html">Pattern&nbsp;Matching</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_assemble_verify.html">Assembly&nbsp;Verification</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="machviz_fme_console.html">FME&nbsp;Console</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="machviz_quadcam.html">QuadCam&nbsp;Zoned&nbsp;Surveillance</a></li>
                                    <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li class="navbar"><a href="main_industry.htm">Industries</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="power.htm">Nuclear Power</a></li>

                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Oil and Gas</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Marine</a></li>

                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="indus_auto.html">Automotive</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="indus_bottlecan.html">Bottling&nbsp;&&nbsp;Canning</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="indus_aerospace.html">Aerospace</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_industry.htm">Other Industries</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="navbar3"><a href="#">Technologies</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="subsea_scanners-1.htm">Underwater&nbsp;Laser&nbsp;Scanning</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="nuke_nm200e_hardware.html">Nuclear&nbsp;Core&nbsp;Validation</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="robot_inspector_land.html">Inspector&nbsp;In-Tank&nbsp;Robot</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="line_systems.htm">Line&nbsp;&&nbsp;Area&nbsp;Scanning</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_noncontact.html">Non-Contact&nbsp;Gauging</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_surface_defect.html">Surface&nbsp;Defects</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_pattern_match.html">Pattern&nbsp;Matching</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="tech_assemble_verify.html">Assembly&nbsp;Verification</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_robotics.htm">Robotics<a href="robot_inspector_land.html"></a>
                            <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="navbar"><a href="main_news_releases.html">Newsroom</a></li>

                    <li class="navbar"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_competence.html">Core&nbsp;Competence</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_about.html">Company&nbsp;Background</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="academic-home-1.html">Academic&nbsp;Website</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_careers.html">Careers&nbsp;at&nbsp;Newton</a></li>
                            <li class="navdrop">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="navdrop"><a href="main_contact.html">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>

                </ul><!-- #EndLibraryItem -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Where's your code?

Comment: Hey @Christian, I added what we currently have above

Comment: I think this might help you, in case you can use Javascript or JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages