# Why am I not able to add content to my html page?

Tags: html, jquery

I found this interesting topic on reusing the navbar for multiple pages, and it works. The issue is when I add tags to my document like an h1 tag it does not show up.

Here is the code that loads the Navbar

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
});
</script>
```

Here is the index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Nav loading starts -->
  <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>

<!-- Nav loading ends -->

<!-- Home/index page content starts -->
<h1> This is the home page</h1>
<!-- Home/index page content ends -->
<script>
$.get("nav.html", function(data){
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the link to the original answer: [How can I reuse a navigation bar on multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)

Here is the Nav.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="nav.css">
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="nav-bar">
  <nav>
    <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="logo"><strong>BuddyUp</strong></div>

    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
      <li><a class="register" href="Login.html">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="icon-burger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </label>

  </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Update:

If I refresh the index page I can see it for a brief moment

Comment: difficult to help you without your html code

Comment: Alright, which HTML code would you need?

Comment: where you put your tag h1 and where you load your navbar

Comment: I added the Html code

Comment: Exactly that is what is happening

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: with your sample there is no problem, h1 is present

Comment: It does not seem to be showing on the site.

Comment: Actually, If I refresh really quickly I can see it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will take another look at my code

Comment: I took another look, and It all seems to be closed. I can post the nav.html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to keep just this for your navbar.html:

```
  <div id="nav-bar">
  <nav>
    <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="logo"><strong>BuddyUp</strong></div>

    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
      <li><a class="register" href="Login.html">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="icon-burger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </label>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternately, OP could use `$("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html #nav-bar")`. See [Loading Page Fragments](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with a different aproach. Your code is executed on the client side and can't read your nav.html file. You need to make a HTTP GET request  to read your file and append it to the innerHTML. You can do this with `jQuery.ajax()` function. In my opinion you should use PHP for the task by using `include('nav.html')`.

Comment: _"You need to make a HTTP GET request to read your file and append it to the innerHTML"_... that's exactly what OP is doing