# How can I re-use the same navigation bar on many responsive pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, responsiveness

I wanna use the same navbar and footer across multiple pages, using the JQuery, as we can see [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages). However, I want a responsive navbar (see the hamburger menu at the corner). So, to do that, I had to load these tags from files. Unfortunately, the script doesn't work anymore. How can I fix it?

[EDIT] Everything works fine by replacing `<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>` with the content of nav.html, but I would like to keep the code distributed. The console returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: toggleButton is null
    <anonymous> file:///home/myProject/script.js:3
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>dummy website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p>home content</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-placeholder"></div>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

nav.html

```
<p>logo</p>
<div class="menu" id="toggleButton">
  <div class="menu-line"></div>
  <div class="menu-line"></div>
  <div class="menu-line"></div>
</div>
<nav class="nav-links" id="nav-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

footer.html

```
<p>footer content</p>
```

style.css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-line {
    background-color: white;
    width: 21px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

main {
    height: 200px;
}

main p{
    color: black;
}

footer {
    background-color: red;
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px){

    .menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .active {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-links ul{
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-links li {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
}
```

script.js

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
const navList = document.getElementById('nav-list');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navList.classList.toggle('active');
});

$(function(){                                                         
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
  $("#footer-placeholder").load("footer.html");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all? Or doesn't work on subsequent pages? Can you see that its' trying to load 'nav.html'? Check your web inspector and console logs and try to identify exactly what isn't working

Comment: @Kinglish I updated the question to provide the information you need.