# Paths are broken in reused elements on a HTML page if the root page is in another folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31954089/3151675) to reuse a header on my pages. Here's how my files look like:

**index.html**

```
<header></header>
[other content]
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**app/index.html**

```
<header></header>
[other content]
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

**header.html**

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="app/index.html">App</a>
```

**js/main.js**

```
$(function(){
  $("header").load("../header.html");
});
```

index.html works fine, but app/index.html doesn't - in the header, the Home link opens app/index.html instead of index.html. This is because it copied header.html's contents and since the current folder is app, it breaks the navigation. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What about using absolute URLs?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want to avoid that, since I'm working in multiple environments

Comment: Use "absolute" paths from the root (`/`) of the app: `href="/index.html"`, `href="/app/index.html"`, ...

Comment: @TamásSengel I thought you wanted to avoid that? I'm glad it worked though.

Comment: I misunderstood absolute, I thought it meant https://example.com/index.html