# Keeping a nav bar (WITH DROP DOWN!!) on all pages without having to copy paste it every time

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, navigation

I would like for a nav bar with some specifications to be kept on every page. I have tried a few solutions on this thread [How can I reuse a navigation bar on multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages) but surprisingly none of them worked for me - it makes the nav bar dissapear completely.

I suspect this is due to the fact that I have a dropdown on my nav bar, and also the specification that it should stay fixed on teh top of each screen when I scroll down.

Here is the navbar code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0a48c3a8e0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="home.html"> Home </a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="start">Start</a>
    <a href="blog">Blog</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbutton"> Interests</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="finance">Finance</a>
                <a href="music">Music</a>
                <a href="language">Language</a>
                <a href="math">Math</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
    </div>

</div>
</html>
```

```
  .navbar {
    background-color: black;
    /*overflow: hidden; WE DONT WANT THIS! prevent drop down*/
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px 

  }
  .navbar a{
    float: left;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none; 
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    color: black;
  }
  .navbar a:active {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    color: aliceblue;
  }

  .dropdown{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .dropdown .dropbutton {
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  }

  .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbutton {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
  }

  /* hide dropdown default*/
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 160px;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: block;
  }

    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
.navbar a.active{
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.navbar input[type=text]{
  float: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar .search-container {
  float: right;
}
.navbar .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I tried most of the JAVASCRIPT solutions on the thread. Because I am a newbie new to this, i want to keep it as close to JS, HTML and CSS first ie with the basics. I also did try some of the JQuery solutions but it did not work unfortunately either.

These are extracts from the things I tried (they all didnt work anyway)

I have a MAIN HOME PAGE called home.html, and my nav bar is in a SEPERATE FILE nameed navbar.html

```
   <!--<script src="nav.js"></script>-->

   <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
   <script>
    $.get("navbar.html", function(data){
        $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the home.html

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0a48c3a8e0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

   <!-- <script id="replaceWithNavbar" src="navbar.js"></script>-->
   <!--<script src="nav.js"></script>-->

   <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
   <script>
    $.get("navbar.html", function(data){
        $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    });
    </script>

    




    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
        <p>heloelkfjashdlkjf
        </p>
    
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="left">test testafdkjhaskfjhalkjfhlakjhflkajh
        asldfkjhalskjfh
        adslfkjhaslkdjfh
        al;ksjfdhalkjh
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="cards-row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card"> <a href="asdf"> asdf</a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card"> <a href="1"> 1 </a> </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card"> <a href="2"> 2 </a> </div>
              </div>
           
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card"><a href="3"> 3</a> </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        <h1>
            Hello World
        </h1>
    </div>


</div>

       





</html>```
````

Comment: Could you show us the complete sourcecode of your home.html? Maybe use [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for that.

Comment: i have updated my post with the home

Comment: You should get rid of `head` tag and it’s content as well the `html` tag it self, it is not allowed inside a `body` tag unless it is imported as `iframe`. If you don’t mind server-side solution, you could try nodeJS or try to use backend language like python or php to include navbar part in the actual html.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include . It's a bit of a faff to set up, but I use Gulp to compile my SCSS and JS files anyway so it's just one more process.

Comment: I wonder why this is so complicated. Is it really that annoying? I thought this was something that alot of companies normally have to do for their websites and thus something quite common. How do THEY do it? Or is it purposely kept a secret?

Comment: I don't know why there is not an easy way, I have used SSIs in the past on personal projects, now I use Gulp. I usually work on CMSs and all that sort of thing is handled by the back end devs using templates.